# Axios 401 with GET, OPTIONS method

Tags: java, api, http, axios

I'm going through an issue with Axios and a Java API.

I'm using this in my

*Application.java*:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

It worked great until today because I needed to use a Basic Auth in the provided api my get request like this (it works  great in both **PostMan** and **Chrome**) :

```
 axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:8180/unv-api/api/rubriques/1527/appli',
      withCredentials: true,
      headers:{ Authorization:'Basic '+btoa('admin' + ':' + 'password')}
      })
```

with axios, an ACTION method is performed and returns a 401 error + a CORS error.

Any idea? Thanks.